# I cannot understand how to plot points instead of row numbers using biplot()

Tags: r, plot, pca

I am trying to use `biplot()` to plot my PCA results. Everything works fine except I want to plot dots (points) instead of row numbers. This is the code I am using:

```
biplot(pca, xlab = "PC1 (43%)", ylab = "PC2 (17%)", pch = 20)
```

But this plots numbers instead of dots.

Comment: See this post here: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/quot-biplot-quot-graphical-options-td903178.html. "For changing the
"point symbols" (which are text by default), try setting xlabs and
ylabs. But of course, an argument "pch" will not have any effect, as
biplot does have no call to "points" or similar, but to "text" only."

Comment: @ZheyuanLi in this case comment from OP isn't really necessary. The question is clear and you have answered it. Purpose fulfilled. :)